# Remove one specific empty git commit with command-line tool

Tags: node.js, git, command-line-tool

For a nodejs command-line tool I add an empty commit to a repo and then want to remove it later.

Later I have at least 3 commits. The **first** one is a merge commit, the **second** one is the empty one I created and the **third** one is likely one from another now merged repo. Now that my tool has done it's task I want to remove the empty commit.

`git rebase --onto  emptyCommitID^ emptyCommitID`
resulted in: `fatal: Does not point to a valid commit 'emptyCommitID^'`

(since the ID is the correct one I assume the commit is invalid due to it being empty)

`git rebase --keep-base --onto  thirdCommit^ headCommit`
resulted in `fatal: cannot combine '--keep-base' with '--onto'`

trying `rebase -i HEAD~3` after the tool had done it's main job resulted in:`fatal: invalid upstream 'HEAD~3'` which might be due to either the empty commit or the merged unrelated histories idk.

I do not want to use `git filter-branch --prune-empty`, because the tool shall leave other potentially empty commits untouched.

(The tool is for merging repos with unrelated histories. I create the empty commit so that files are staged when merged instead of committed directly which also happens when the `--no-commit` flag is set in an just initialized repo without prior commits)

maybe it is possible to solve this with `git rebase --interactive`, but I had the described problem with the invalid upstream and view this as very difficult to implement with a command line tool, mostly using `exec` to execute it's commands. Do you know a solution?

Answer (score 0):

I think `git rebase --onto emptyCommitID^ emptyCommitID` should work.

`fatal: Does not point to a valid commit 'emptyCommitID^'` means that the emptyCommitID has no parent. It contradicts that the second one is the empty one and the first one is its parent.